# Htaccess - If cookie is set

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !User_is_LoggedIn=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

The goal of the code is to make it so that any unauthenticated user can't access that part of the site without logging in, so it checks the cookie I set at login to see if it exists/is equal to 1, and then denies access via sending them to a login page if the user is not logged in. However, it is returning true/false regardless of the status of the cookie so I must be doing something wrong.

I have checked to make sure that the cookie is being set (and deleted) properly.

Comment: String comparison needs an equal sign, I think – `!=User_is_LoggedIn=1`. But that would still test for strict equality, and `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` contains _all_ cookies, so if you have more than one set at any time, I would not expect this to match. I think this needs a regular expression to check for the specific name=value pair inside the potentially longer string. https://serverfault.com/a/566109

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. And it wasn't something that could've been fixed here either, I just mistook the actual cookie name. In my other code it was User_is_LoggedIn, but when I checked the actual cookie in the browser developer mode it was User.is.LoggedIn instead. Once I switched it the whole thing worked.